# Correct way to change the subnet of an existing podman network

Tags: podman, cni

I'm using podman v3.0.2 and trying to change the subnet of an **existing** podman network.
I searched the podman and CNI documentations, but I could not find the way.
Is there any correct way to change the network of an existing podman network?

### Background

I already created some containers with podman default network (subnet: 10.88.0.1/16) and want to use the subnet of it for others.
I think the simplest way is changing the subnet of it and want to know it.

### The way I tried

I managed to change it by the following procedures, but it does not seem officially documented.
Also, I think the OS reboot is redundant and want to avoid it.

1. Stop the all containers connecting to the network.
2. Change `subnet` section in the CNI network file.

   - https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/cni/87-podman-bridge.conflist#L17
3. Reboot OS
4. Start the containers stopped in the procedure1.

I used this way referred from the changing the DNS in the CNI network file in the podman documentation.
https://podman.io/getting-started/network#using-dns-in-container-networks

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit stale, but maybe other folks will find this answer useful. What caught my eye was:

> 3. Reboot OS

You shouldn't need to reboot your OS.

The following procedure works for me:

1. Shut down all the containers on the network.
2. Remove the bridge device by running `ip link del cni-podman0` (or whatever bridge name is configured for that network)
3. Edit the CNI file in `/etc/cni/net.d`
4. Start the containers you started in step 1.

The above steps are all performed as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

### Default network:

In RHEL 9, the default configuration is derived from `/usr/share/containers/containers.conf`. You can copy this file to `/etc/containers/containers.conf` and set the `default_network` variable if you would like to use a different subnet for the default network. You can then apply the config with `systemctl restart podman`

### Manually added network:

If you created a network with `podman network create test-net` then the config will be in `/etc/containers/networks/test-net.json` by default, but could be in `/etc/cni` if you have configured the cni backend in `containers.conf`.

See `/usr/share/man/man1/podman-network-*` for more info